# Is there continuous $f$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx = 0$ and $\int_0^1 (1-x)^n f(x) dx \neq 0$ for some $n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> I would like to find (or show that it is not possible) a continuous function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ satisfying
>   $$f(0)=f(1)=\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 0$$
>   and such that for *some* positve integer $n$ we have
>   $$\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_0^1 (1-x)^n f(x) dx \neq 0.$$

Since
$$0 = \int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 xf(x) dx + \int_0^1 (1-x)f(x) dx,$$
it follows that $\int_0^1 xf(x)dx$ and $\int_0^1 (1-x)f(x)dx$ are both or neither zero. Hence $n$ must be at least $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x(x-1)(1+ax+bx^2+cx^3)$ then $f(0)=f(1)=0$.
For a given integer $n\geq 2$ solve the following linear system with respect to the coefficients $a,b,c$,
$$\begin{cases}\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 0\\
\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx = 0\\
\int_0^1 (1-x)^n f(x) dx=1
\end{cases}$$
It can be shown that the above system has a unique solution.